# how to calculate hours and Minutes with Two times in Typescript

Tags: typescript

var startime = 11.30;
var endtime = 13.00;

The Expected output was 1.30.

can anyone give me a typescript code for that!.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include *any* attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what *you* want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not clear about what you are trying to do... take this code as your reference...

```
let startime = '11.30'; 
let endtime = '13.0';

let [sTimeHour, sTimeMin] = startime.split('.')
let [eTimeHour, eTimeMin] = endtime.split('.')

let startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, sTimeHour, sTimeMin, 0);
let endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, eTimeHour, eTimeMin, 0);

let diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
let hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);

diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
let minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);

console.log(`diff is ${hours} hours and ${minutes} minutes`)
```